# How we can pass data?

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper

How we can pass data of a `methods` `MainAntivity` to another `class` type `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
For example we have :(`MainActivity.java`)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
public String xxx(){
    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    return PACKAGE_NAME;
    }
}
```

And another class is :(`DB.java`)

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
  MainActivity cc = new MainActivity();
  Log.d("test",(String) cc.xxx());
}
```

But above code not work.

Comment: what you need is basic android java tutorials. because this code involves some fundamental errors such as instantiating activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate activity classes this way. Use a separate class instead, where you can define methods which you'd like to use somewhere else. In your case, receiving package name, I'd do something like this

```
public class PackageNameHelper
{
    private Context mContext;

    public PackageNameHelper(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public String GetPackageName(){
        return mContext.getPackageName();
    }

}
```

Then in your activity / SQLite helper you'd do:

```
PackageNameHelper helper = new PackageNameHelper(getApplicationContext());
String packageName = helper.getPackageName()
```

Or you can make the helper class static, that way Context must be passed directly int the getPackageName() method, like

```
public class PackageNameHelper
{

    public static String GetPackageName(Context context){
        return context.getPackageName();
    }

}
```

and use it like

```
//Where context is an instance of a context
String packageName = PackageNameHelper.getPackageName(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not instantiate your Activities, In your case in my opinion a good way can be defining a constructor for your `DB` class that takes an argument as context for this application. Than you can save it in a member variable and use it whenever you need.

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  Context mContext;

  /* Constructor */
  public DB(Context context) {
      mContext = context;
  }

}
```

If you need to package name within your `DB` class codes, you can use `mContext.getPackageName()` to retrieve package name.